# ajax json no turning back

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
function register() {

    hideshow('loading', 1);
    //error(0);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'submit.php',
        data: $('#regForm').serialize(),
        success: function (Cevap) {

            if (Cevap.msg == "1") {
                $('div.durumkayit').html('<div class="tamam">Sisteme Giriyoruz...</div>');
                setTimeout("window.location = '../search/anamodul.php';", 1000);
            } else {
                $('div.durumkayit').html('<div class="hata">' + Cevap.msg + '</div>');
            }

            hideshow('loading', 0);
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

php code

```
$sonuc=array('msg'=>'Tüm alanların doldurulmasi zorunludur');
echo json_encode($sonuc);
```

Comment: How about adding some more information?

Comment: what do you mean by `no turning back`?

Comment: Is the `success` handler called? Is `submit.php` requested? And don't use `setTimeout` this way, just make a new (anonymous) function and use that.

Comment: `no turning back` probably means _callback_, so I guess the OP means that `success` is not called.

Comment: Maybe your JSON is not in UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code. and it's all right.
The only things that could be happening are the following:

1. `#regForm` doesn't exist when you are calling `register()`
2. hideshow is undefined or has errors
3. Your ajax url is wrong

However, adding an error handler to your ajax call would help A LOT:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
     alert("ERROR!!\n" + status);
  }
});
```

It seems you have a json `parseerror`. But first test it.

Check your file encoding. As you have special (too special!) characters, better if you use utf-8 everywhere.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: my php file  characters utf- 8 but css and js file utf-8 Does not describe is this problem?